# Operations on Column Entries

Tags: r, excel

I want to do Excel-like operations on a column. This has been asked before, for example here: [Excel like column operations in R dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324515/excel-like-column-operations-in-r-dataframe)

However I don't find the answers all that helpful, because I do not want to specify operations for each of my 1700+ rows. So my problem is this:

I have two columns `Data` and `Close`. I want another column whose entries are `log(x_{n+1}/x_n)` for `n=1,...,1719`, `x_i` in `Close` (2nd column). The answers in the link suggest specifying operations based on row numbers, but I can't very well spend time doing that for 1720 rows.

Here are some other answers to the question, which I don't understand: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Log-difference-in-a-dataframe-column-td3221225.html

Using `as.ts` does not work, the result is just 0. I need something like

```
> df$LReturn <- log(df$Close / df$Close)
```

that specifies that the first entry in this new column is one, and all the others are the `(n+1):th` over the `n:th`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(Hmisc)

set.seed(3)
df = data.frame(date=1:10, close=25+rnorm(10))
df$Lreturn = log(df$close/Lag(df$close,1))

#   date    close      Lreturn
#1     1 24.03807           NA
#2     2 24.70747  0.027467119
#3     3 25.25879  0.022068343
#4     4 23.84787 -0.057479317
#5     5 25.19578  0.054981806
#6     6 25.03012 -0.006596575 
#7     7 25.08542  0.002206653
#8     8 26.11661  0.040284808
#9     9 23.78114 -0.093678580 
#10   10 26.26737  0.099434498
```

You can also do this base `R`:

```
df$LreturnBaseR = log(c(df$close[-1],NA)/df$close)
```

Comment: Thanks. I get two error messages, "Error in library(Hmisc) : there is no package called ‘Hmisc’" and "Error: could not find function "Lag"". What does library() and set.seed() accomplish?

Comment: `library(Hmisc)` loads the Hmisc library ... so to beloaded it needs to be install before, do `install.packages('Hmisc')`

Comment: This is the reason I added a base R (without package installation) solution. The base R code will run without loading the library.

Comment: `set.seed()` put a starting point on the random generator so that we can have the same data.

Comment: Alright. So with my actual data I won't need set.seed()? Anyway, that stuff works great, could you explain log(Lag(df$close,-1)/df$close) in detail? The numbers in the new column are correct except that NA should be in row 1 and row n should be in row (n+1). I tried adjusting using lag 1 instead, then the numbers are in correct position but with the "wrong" sign.

Comment: I edited my code it is rather `log(df$close/Lag(df$close,1))`. But by the way lag function is pretty verbose by itself, and think about using `?Lag` ... I will not explain every command!

Comment: Ah yes, now it works. I tried log(df$close/Lag(df$close,1)) but I got completely different numbers - because I got the parentheses wrong. Alright, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: No problem! consider closing the topic by ticking the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apply log properties and the `base` `diff` function:

```
df$LrReturn<-c(diff(log(df$close)),NA)
```